# Failed to send email from PHP

Tags: php, email

I use PHP version 5.4.7, win 7 x64, localhost
this is my code:

```
mail("my_gmail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $user\n");
```

I've changed the file `php.ini`:
1. remove semicon in `extension=php_openssl.dll`
2. change into

```
[mail function]   
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and replace all existing code in `sendmail.ini` into
[sendmail]

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log  
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

but i still cant received the email, anyone know my mistakes?plz

Comment: Isn't Gmails smtp port `465`?

Comment: i've tried that but still can't

Comment: thanks guys, im already found solution, it just need to restart xampp services. Just it and done. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can using 3rd party libraries, here are examples how to implement:

***(Both are work with TLS & SSL)***

### 1. [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

```
$mailSubj = "Here is the subject";
$mailBody = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mailText = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";
$mailAddr = "myclient@gmail.com";
$mailName = "My Client";

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    //ssl using 465, it is work
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    //tls using 587, it also work too
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'your_email@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'your_password';

    $mail->From = 'your_email@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Admin88hk';
    $mail->addAddress($mailAddr, $mailName);

    $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "PHPMailer - " . $mailSubj;
    $mail->Body    = $mailBody;
    $mail->AltBody = $mailText;
$mail->send();
```

### 2. [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html-mails.html) (Version 1.12)

```
$mailSubj = "Here is the subject";
$mailBody = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mailText = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";
$mailAddr = "myclient@gmail.com";
$mailName = "My Client";

require_once("Zend/Mail.php");
require_once("Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php");

$mailServer = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mailServerCfgSsl = array(
        'ssl' => 'ssl',
        'port' => 465,
        'auth' => 'login',
        'username' => 'your_email@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'your_password'
    );

$mailServerCfg = array(
        'ssl' => 'tls',
        'port' => 587,
        'auth' => 'login',
        'username' => 'your_email@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'your_password'
    );

//ssl using 465, it is work
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($mailServer, $mailServerCfgSsl);

//tls using 587, it also work too
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($mailServer, $mailServerCfg);

Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);


$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
    $mail->setSubject( "Zend - " . $mailSubj );
    $mail->setBodyHtml( $mailBody );
    $mail->setBodyText( $mailText );
    $mail->addTo( $mailAddr , $mailName );
$mail->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Karl said, the SMTP port Google uses is 465, not 587.

Comment: still can't, i've changed it into 465

Comment: Open this [Link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?hl=en) and follow instructions. Google servers block any attempts from unknown servers so once you click on captcha check every thing will be fine

Comment: Allen, you should put a solution for that and I'll delete mine. Thanks. Comment me back when you have so I know to delete :)

Comment: @Allen still can't, i've changed SMTP port into 465 and follow your link and continue captcha, when i check my gmail still none

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing encryption type(ssl/tsl). for gmail its using (ssl) encryption.

Comment: change smtp_server = ssl://smtp.gmail.com

Comment: i change my smtp_server into ssl://smtp.gmail.com, but stil it didnt work. is it because i used x64 maybe?